# Control Scheduling in JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to prevent normal users from scheduling a report.
Only administrator will have the right to schedule report.
Is it possible with `JasperReports Server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You should edit the ***`jasperserver\WEB-INF\actionModel-search.xml`*** file.

You need to find the definition of **`ScheduleAction`** action in this file and add the condition for the **ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR** role:

```xml
<context name="resource_menu">
    <simpleAction labelKey="RM_BUTTON_RUN" action="invokeRedirectAction" actionArgs="RunResourceAction"
                  clientTest="canBeRun" className="up"/>
    <condition test="isSupportedDevice">
        <simpleAction labelKey="RM_BUTTON_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND" action="invokeRedirectAction" actionArgs="RunInBackgroundResourceAction"
                      clientTest="canBeRunInBackground" className="up"/>
            <condition test="checkAuthenticationRoles" testArgs="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">                         
                <simpleAction labelKey="RM_BUTTON_SCHEDULE_REPORT" action="invokeRedirectAction" actionArgs="ScheduleAction"
                              clientTest="canBeScheduled" className="up"/>
            </condition>          
        <simpleAction labelKey="RM_BUTTON_WIZARD" action="invokeRedirectAction" actionArgs="EditResourceAction"
                      clientTest="canResourceBeEdited" className="up"/>
    </condition>
```

I've just add the `<condition test="checkAuthenticationRoles" testArgs="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR">` for the `ScheduleAction` action.

After that you should restart the application server (Tomcat).

Comment: Still one very silly question. How to restart Jasper Server? What I used to do is restart the machine.

Comment: What application server are you using with JR Server? What OS?

Comment: You can restart Tomcat via restarting the **`jasperreportsTomcat`** Windows Service or you can restart it manually in cmd from the `$jasperreports-server$\apache-tomcat\bin` folder: 1) run `catalina stop` 2) after stopping and editing the xml file run `catalina start`

Comment: Thanks a lot once again, Alex.

Comment: This solution only prevents the right-click schedule action.  If there is a report with an existing schedule, users can still edit an existing schedule or create a new schedule for that report.  They can simply click on the clock (schedule) button next to the report.